# Using setTimeout to add cooldown time to a button

Tags: javascript, button, settimeout

I try to create an object method called coolDown, when a button is clicked, it will disable the button and unlock it afer cooling time is over.

But when I test it, it will disable the button, but, did not unlock the button after the cooling time is over, why is it?

```
var btncd = new test();

function test() {
}

test.prototype.coolDown = function() {
    document.getElementById("cd").disabled = "true";
    setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById("cd").disabled = "false";}, 2000);
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("cd").onclick = btncd.coolDown;
}
```

Appreciate for your answer..

Comment: yes, I set the disabled property to false, isn't that meaning removed?

Comment: `disabled` should have `Boolean` value assigned..not `string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be

```
document.getElementById("cd").disabled = false; // without ""
```

`Boolean("false");` is evaluated to `true`

Comment: Basically `non-empty-string` is evaluated as `TRUE`

Comment: Yes! Thank you for the answer!